# "На радость владельцам" или "на радость владельцев"?

Tags: согласование, падежи, окончания

"На радость владельцам" или "На радость владельцев"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**на ра́дость**](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-ortho-term-47614.htm)
1. наречие
1) Чтобы были радость, удача, успех.
2) Употр. как вводное словосочетание, выражая удовлетворение по поводу чего-л.; к счастью.
**2. предлог**
***с дат. пад.*** Употребляется при указании на кого-либо, для чьего удовольствия делается что-либо.

На радость (кому?) владельцам; на радость людям; на радость детям.

*Небо был ясным, в глаза светило теплое солнышко, а на берегу царило веселье от того, что тонущий человек был спасен, а сам спаситель плескался здесь же **на радость отдыхающим людям.***

Answer (score 3):

Падежи "получателей" радости по-разному сочетаются с предлогами.

**На радость** владельц**ам** (на радость **кому** что-то делается, кому этим доставляется радость).

> Театр у Никитских ворот давал своё представление **на радость**
>   русскоязычным **жителям** Южной Калифорнии. (Александр Половец, БП. Между
>   прошлым и будущим.)

**К радости** владельц**ев** (**к чьей** радости привело случившееся). Обычно это о *моменте наступления* радости в прошедшем времени.

> **К радости жителей** Калининского района, выбор пал на их округ.
>   (журнал Огонёк, февраль 1962 г.)

Answer (score 2):

> “На радость владельцам” или “на радость владельцев”?

Нужно различать словосочетание "на радость" в роли предлога и слово *радость* с предлогом *на*.

В первом случае предлог "на радость" употребляется с дательным падежом:

> Судя по количеству икры, завезенной в ресторан, рыбам условия проживания нравятся, поэтому они **на радость владельцам бизнеса** мечут икру просто-таки по-стахановски. [Галина САПОЖНИКОВА. Чемпионат по поеданию деликатеса: Черная икра со скоростью 20 тысяч рэ в минуту // Комсомольская правда, 2012.04.23]

Во втором существительное "радость" управляет родительным падежом:

> Никто не обращает внимание **на радость владельцев бизнеса**, вызванную ростом доходов от продажи икры.

Answer (score 1):

Получается, что и так и так правильно: на радость кому — владельцам и на радость чью (кого) — владельцев.